Microgravity before re-entry on the Polaris Dawn mission
While the astronauts were still in orbit preparing for atmospheric reentry there was already a clear acceleration noticeable.
I'm linking to one of the many YouTube copies of the original X live stream (here the "NASASpaceflight" enthusiasts) because I can have a URL containing a timestamp: 

 This is the beginning of a sequence in which a tethered pen held by the astronaut on the left floats with clear and significant acceleration "upward" upon release, as if it were a helium balloon on Earth. Other items are also moving "up". This is different from the free fall at the beginning of the mission when the "zero gravity indicator" is released and floats without heading in any particular direction.
Clearly, there is some, as I suppose, deceleration. The X live stream commentary, although not very clear, seems to indicate that the deceleration burn is going on. On the other hand, the live images of the nose cone do not show any thruster action.
Also, would that deceleration be so weak?

Not sure about the primary question, but 4 Draco thrusters against a dry Crew Dragon accelerates about 1/50 g.

@RussellBorogove That would fit the observation, for this layman ;-).

That 'upward' force is indeed the Draco thrusters firing for deorbit. It's a quite small acceleration, but enough to make a pen fly around, clearly.
As to why the nose thrusters are not visibly firing, I'm not sure of the thruster usage pattern, but it's entirely possible that the deorbit burn does not make use of the nosecone thrusters at all and depends entirely on the rear thrusters (which are a good six feet away from the nosecone and wouldn't produce a particularly visible plume from the perspective of the nosecone camera). I could theorize that this is because they want to be able to use the same deorbit plan whether the nosecone is open or closed -- for example, if the nosecone was jammed shut for some reason -- but I have no evidence or source for that.
I'm not sure how to answer why the thrust is so weak. The thrusters put out what they put out. The deorbit is done entirely by the Draco thrusters at 400 N each, not the heavy duty SuperDracos.

It is quite amazing to me that a few minutes of such a slow deceleration suffice to knock a body out of orbit. (I know, it's a nudge, not a knock -- I wanted language with effect! --, but with spectacular results since it is introduced into a non-linear system. Perhaps the thing to actually appreciate is the regular circular orbit with a precision of (I suppose) 1 or 2% maximum; it doesn't take a large deviation to deorbit.

@Peter-Reinstate Monica - it makes you wonder what alternate methods could be used to deorbit if the normal engines malfunction. Like doing some venting, etc. I'm sure it wouldn't give you an immediate deorbit like you get with a normal deorbit burn, but maybe it would be enough to cause a deorbit within a few days or so. And of course you would have no control over where you land.

@StevePemberton 90 m/s (as for the Shuttles, or whatever they used here) is still a lot. Trying that by venting is similar to accelerating a truck to 270 km/h by pointing a leaf blower out the back. The difference between few days and few hours is not large.

Reasonable people can disagree, but I wouldn't call 7 minutes "a few", and as I understand, that was about half the usual burn time for a deorbit from the ISS because you can get away with a shorter burn if you're in an more eccentric orbit. (And even that 15 minute burn from the ISS is shorter than the Shuttle's 20 minute deorbit, since the shuttle was so much heavier.)

@asdfex - for sure with the Shuttle, I was thinking only about current spacecraft.

@DarthPseudonym a typical shuttle deorbit burn time was 2-3 minutes, not 20. https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/USA007587%20Rev%20A%20-%20Shuttle%20Crew%20Operations%20Manual%2020081215.pdf page 844

@OrganicMarble - I'm guessing they could have deorbited Shuttle with just one OMS engine if needed?

@StevePemberton or the RCS jets. Even the forward jets, if you get real deep in the failures.

@asdfex - also I would think the delta-v used in a nominal deorbit is based on a shallow entry trajectory. I wonder if there are re-entry profiles that require slightly less delta-v, but that come in steeper (up to what is survivable). Or is it the same amount required regardless of the entry angle?

@StevePemberton I suppose less delta-v leads to a shallower entry? At some point it's only a skim, possibly repeatedly, until enough energy is lost to properly enter for good.

@Peter-Reinstate Monica - in normal usage yes. I just didn't know if there are tricks they could do to maybe make the orbit more eccentric prior to the deorbit burn, but I guess in the end the total delta-v would still add up the same if not more.

@OrganicMarble Okay, you have the expertise here. I was trying to find out how long the shuttle's deorbit was, and I saw on the wikipedia page for the OMS lists the burn time as "1250 seconds" for deorbit, which is just a hair over 20 minutes. Maybe that's some extreme never-really-used case where they could technically deorbit with only one working OMS thruster or something, I'm not sure. I saw the 1250 seconds quoted elsewhere as well (though not in what you'd call a primary source).

@DarthPseudonym Not responsible for wikipedia screw-ups. 20 minutes would have been a really, really long OMS burn. Like, desperately trying to get into orbit long. I linked to a reference. Also the OMS training manual they give as a reference on the wiki says it's three minutes (page 3.3). Add shrug emoticon here.
